# Returning an empty array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service call as getSectionDetails. When I call this in my component.ts class it only returns an empty array. I m taking eventId from previous page. It will print in console. So there is no problem it comes to the next page(section page). I need to send the eventId with getSectionDetail call. I need to take section details when I enter the section page. But in this case when I entered the section page it returns an empty array

```
import {AfterViewInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Section} from '../../../interfaces/section';
import { SectionService } from 'app/services/section.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'select-section',
    templateUrl: './select-section.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SelectSectionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
    eventId: string;
    sectionList: Section[] = [];
    constructor(private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute,
                private _router: Router,
                private _sectionService: SectionService) {
        this.eventId = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.getSectionDetails();
    }
    getSectionDetails() {
        this._sectionService
            .getSectionDetails(this.eventId)
            .subscribe((sectionList: Section[]) => {
                this.sectionList = sectionList;
                console.log(this.sectionList);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending correctly the param?

Comment: Is the end point return nonempty array in postman using same parameters?

Comment: params are correct and end points return values in postman

Comment: then try to modify this code to be
this._sectionService.getSectionDetails(this.eventId).subscribe((sectionList) => {console.log(this.sectionList);});
to see what printed in the consol if it print object it mean that returned json string not an array of Section and can't be casted. also if you can add print screen from response object preview in browser network will be helpfull .